# capacitor framework hello world basic html not working

Tags: capacitor

I tried creating my first app in capcaitor.

Just basic html

```
<html>
<body> ABC 123 </body>
</html>
```

pasted it in www/index.html

npx cap copy; npx cap open ios

run it in ios

shows a blank screen; no text

Comment: Are there no other errors? In the Xcode project, check the file `public/index.html` to see if those changes are actually being coppied.

Comment: yes content is there, but looks like capacitor.js file was not there; instead i found cordova.js

Comment: In iios simulator; is it possible to debug webview in js, like chrome inspect /